# Ruby xcodeproj throwing `normalize_source_tree': [Xcodeproj] Unrecognized source tree option `Auto` (RuntimeError)

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode-project

Iam using xcodeproj for adding a  static library to my xcodeproject and iam getting an error in the new_file method the error is : `normalize_source_tree': [Xcodeproj] Unrecognized source tree option`Auto` (RuntimeError) any help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you doing something like this?

```
project.new_file(file_path, "Auto");
```

If so, modify your line to follow this syntax:

```
project['Auto'].new_file(file_path);
```

Does that solve your problem? If not, please post the line giving you the error.